# "It is me whom she loves" or "It is I whom she loves" which one is grammatically correct?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, syntactic-analysis

> **It is me** whom she loves
>   or
>   **It is I** whom she loves

Because I know that "It is I" is grammatically correct.

Comment: *It's me* can be just as grammatically correct. It just depends on whom you ask. The most natural formulation of your phrase (for me) is *It's me she loves ".

Comment: This answer should make things clearer http://english.stackexchange.com/a/125694/44619

Comment: The canonical answer is [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/17745/300).

Comment: @guifa To me, the _only_ properly natural way to phrase this (as in the only way I'd ever actually say it myself) is “I'm the one she loves”. No sentence that begins with “it is [pronoun] [relative clause]” is truly idiomatic and natural to my ear: they consistently come off as clumsy and stilted-sounding.

Answer (score -2):

You would have to break this down into two separate clauses to understand which pronouns you should use.

"It is me" whom she loves can be broken down into two parts.

"Whom does she love?" "She loves me"

Remember what is doing your action because that will determine whether you use I or me.

"Me" does not do the action. "She" does it.

She does it to "whom" and she does it to "me"

Comment: This "answer" is poorly constructed. Is it an answer? There isn't even a sentence. You can do better than this

Comment: *Me* is not the object. The object is *whom*. *Me* is an entirely different clause. That said, it is still vastly preferred over *I* (see the [linked question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/17745/300)), but not because it's the object of anything.

Comment: Basically, this question comes down to the issue of the construction "This is + personal pronoun". Which one is correct? This is he/This is him - This is we/This is us etc. The answer is simple. According to the academic norm it should be - "It's I", but in colloquial speech people tend to say "It's me".