# When saying "this one" when referring to yourself, is it first or third person?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I have been playing a RP forum game and I believe that one of the other players may be locked into first/third person every post he makes. Which one it is doesn't change it from a gameplay view but it got me intrigued to find out which one it was. Here are some examples of how he uses it

> This one bears no grudge
>
> This one can neither confirm nor deny this accusation

In each of these, the subject of *this one* is himself. On one side I feel like it is third person because it is how I could address him as a third person. But the fact that he is talking about himself makes it feel synonymous with the word I and has the same impression which I feel is indicative of first person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatically third person singular, no matter whom it actually refers to.  That’s why the verb there is *bears* not *bear*.

Even [blatant self-referral](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/88319) can wind up being grammatically third-person:

> Silly me **has** better things to do.

There is no question that these are all third-person uses, even if silly you **thinks** otherwise. :)

Answer (score -1):

'I' (or 'me' in objective case) is the only first person word in English.

Comment: "We" is first person

Comment: Yeah, I forgot.