# Referring to an unfortunate woman: "Poor her" or "Poor she"?

Tags: grammar, declension

I am guessing "she" even if the most common way to express this is "her" - I think we use nominative case since the woman is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: What sentence? Are you wanting to say something about this poor person?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why do we use the object instead of the subject pronoun in constructions like "stupid me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2075/191178)

Comment: @StuartF: someone suffering a misfortune simply says, "Poor me" instead of "Poor I".

Comment: What we would say about her is “Poor thing” or “Poor dear.”

Comment: @Xanne: because the words "thing" and "dear" do not change based on whether subject or object makes this easy. in english, declension only occurs afaik with pronouns. i sure was puzzled at first by declension in languages which use it extensively and could not get a straight answer from the foolish person i asked to explain it to me as a kid. he said we did not have it in english while all he had to do was discuss "I" and "me" for example.

Comment: @releseabe Please note: you should use a capital letter for the word **E**nglish, the pronoun "I", and for the first word of a sentence.

Comment: We say "poor you", but I've never heard anyone say "Poor her" - we would use her name or say "Poor woman" or use another noun, as Xanne says.

Comment: "Poor her" sounds OK to me. [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Poor+her&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @BillJ: The ngrams link would be more convincing if the examples weren't all along the lines of "... was poor. Her next ...."! But I agree that "Poor her" sounds OK; I've almost certainly used it, even.

Comment: @psmears I don't follow you. The Ngram I linked to was "Poor her". The same applies if a full stop is included making a full sentence [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Poor+her.&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @BillJ: If you click on the buttons to see what examples it's included in its count, it gives results [like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22poor%20her%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2017,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en), which include mostly of "... poor. Her ..." - or are you saying that doesn't match what it's including in the graph?